# Laravel: getting and combining values from radio button

Tags: laravel, radio-button, laravel-5.8

I'm currently making a sort of 'quiz' to get a user's starter class based on their given answers. A personality test, basically.

Here is an example of my forms

```
<div class="form-group">
            <h4>{{Form::label('title', 'Favourite season?')}}<br></h4>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="option">
                    Spring - {{Form::radio('q4', 1, false)}}<br>
                    Summer - {{Form::radio('q4', 2, false)}}<br>
                    Autumn - {{Form::radio('q4', 3, false)}}<br>
                    Winter - {{Form::radio('q4', 4, false)}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My controller is barren at the moment, seeing as I am not sure how to grab each value, then combine them into a final result

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'q1' => 'required',
            'q2' => 'required',
            'q3' => 'required',
            'q4' => 'required',
            'q5' => 'required',
            'q6' => 'required',
            'q7' => 'required',
            'q8' => 'required',
            'q9' => 'required',
            'q10' => 'required',
        ]);

        return $request;
    }
}
```

My post correctly gets the values from the inputs, I just need to know how I can get these into one final score and store it into the database

I have tried using JavaScript, however I cannot figure out how to get the result into the controller to store in the database.

Comment: what do you mean by getting into one final score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could try to name your radio inputs as an array so then you can retrieve the values in one shot:

```
{{ Form::radio('q[3]', 1, false) }}
{{ Form::radio('q[3]', 2, false) }}
...


{{ Form::radio('q[4]', 1, false) }}
{{ Form::radio('q[4]', 2, false) }}
...
```

Then in your Controller you can get all the values into a single array:

```
$values = $request->input('q', []);
```

Then you can get the sum of this pretty easily:

```
$sum = array_sum($values);
```

You would probably want to do some validation to make sure you are getting the right amount of inputs within certain value ranges.